# I've created a php function that builds 7 check boxes, 7 product drop down boxes and 7 quantity boxes which pertain to each prouduct.

Tags: php, sql, for-loop, foreach

I'm populating the select boxes with data from my database. (sql server 2008).

Here is my function:

```
function sample_items($product_types = array('METER KIT', 'TEST STRIP', 'LANCET', 'CONTROL SOLUTION', 'LANCING DEVICE', 'BATTERY', 'MISC'))
        {
        $a = array();
        $i = 0;
        $def = $product_types;
        foreach($product_types as $k)
            {
            $qty = sql::one_row("select min_, max_, interval from event.dbo.product_type where product_type = " . hexstr($k));
            $label = str_replace('CONTROL SOLUTION', 'C/S', $k); 
            $label = str_replace('LANCING DEVICE', 'L/D', $label); 
            $a[] = input_check("items[ok][$i]")->label($label);
            if ($k == 'TEST STRIP')
                {
                $a[] = input_select("items[ptcode][$i]", sql::two_column_array("select rtrim(a.CODE_), case when B.id IS NULL THEN rtrim(a.DESCRIPTION_) else 'BACKORDER:'+RTRIM(a.DESCRIPTION_) end
                    from PACWARE.ADS.PTDME a left outer join event.dbo.backorder b on a.CODE_=b.ptcode where a.MEDICAREID = 'SAMP' and a.DESCRIPTION_ like '%STRIP%'"), 1)->label('')->same_line()->set_class('wide2');
                }
            else if ($k == 'LANCET')
                {
                $a[] = input_select("items[ptcode][$i]", sql::two_column_array("select rtrim(a.CODE_), case when B.id IS NULL THEN rtrim(a.DESCRIPTION_) else 'BACKORDER:'+RTRIM(a.DESCRIPTION_) end
                    from PACWARE.ADS.PTDME a left outer join event.dbo.backorder b on a.CODE_=b.ptcode where a.MEDICAREID = 'SAMP' and a.DESCRIPTION_ like '%LANCET%'"), 1)->label('')->same_line()->set_class('wide2');
                }
            else if ($k == 'MISC')
                {
                $a[] = input_select("items[ptcode][$i]", \Ptdme::items_by_product_type(array('SAMPLE PRODUCT','MISCELLANEOUS SUPPLIES')), 1)->label('')->same_line()->set_class('wide2');
                }
            else { $a[] = input_select("items[ptcode][$i]", \Ptdme::items_by_product_type($k), 1)->label('')->same_line()->set_class('wide2'); }
            if (!empty($qty)) $a[] = input_select("items[qty][$i]", range($qty['min_'], $qty['max_'], $qty['interval']))->label();
            else $a[] = input_select("items[qty][$i]", range(0, 100))->label();
            $i++;
            }
        return input_group('Items', $a)->whole();
        }
```

It's housed in an input group which is just a little table with some css.

[image: input_group('Items', $a)->whole();]

After it is saved I've created another function to build an "event form" for this samples page.

Here's that function:

```
function new_pt_ss()
    {
    if ($this->create_npc_SS)
        {
        $task_id = '13';
        if (sql::value("select 1 from event.dbo.event where task_id =" . hexstr($task_id). " and status = 1 and patient_id = " . $this->patient->hex))
            return Message::add('New Patient Sample CC already exists. Event not created.', 'warn');
        $defs = array('METER KIT', 'TEST STRIP', 'LANCET', 'CONTROL SOLUTION', 'LANCING DEVICE', 'BATTERY', 'MISC');    
        $task_params = array();
        $oks = $this->get_oks();
        $oks_hex = array();
        foreach ($oks as $k=>$v) $oks_hex[] = hexstr($k);
        $qtys = zip($this->items['ptcode'], $this->items['qty']);
        foreach ($defs as $x)
            {
            $me = 0;
            foreach ($pt_types as $num=>$row)
                {
                if ($row['ev_product_type'] == $x)
                    {
                    $task_params["{$row['ev_product_type']}"] = $row['ptcode'];
                    $task_params["{$row['ev_product_type']}_qty"] = $qtys[$row['ptcode']];
                    if ($x == 'control_solution') $task_params['cs_bill'] = '1';
                    else if ($x == 'lancing_device') $task_params['lancing_bill'] = '1';
                    unset($pt_types[$num]);
                    $me = 1;//continue 2; // preserves sorting instead of continue
                    }
                }
            }
        $task_params = array_merge($task_params, array('ship_date'=>$this->ship_date
            ,'urgent'=>$this->urgent
            ,'valid_po'=>$this->valid_po
            ,'shipping_method'=>$this->shipping_method
            ,'reason'=>$this->reason
            ,'on_insulin'=>$this->on_insulin
            ,'patient_on_insulin'=>$this->patient_on_insulin
            ));
        Message::check($this->patient->event()->create($task_id,  $task_params), "Create Sample CC event.");
        return "NEW PT Sample CC EVENT TO BILLING FOR DOS $this->ship_date.";
        }
    }
```

After it's submitted if there isn't an event already created for sample ss otherwise known as `$task_id = '13';` it will create the event and populate these fields:

```
,'urgent'=>$this->urgent
,'valid_po'=>$this->valid_po
,'shipping_method'=>$this->shipping_method
,'reason'=>$this->reason
,'on_insulin'=>$this->on_insulin
,'patient_on_insulin'=>$this->patient_on_insulin
```

The problem is i'm not sure how to populate all the check boxes and select boxes in my for each loop.

These are the field names that need to be populated on the event form:

```
<tr><td>Meter</td><td><?php sbox('part1',ptdme('E0607'),1, "' onChange=\" reason_swap(this); \" '"); ?></td><input type='hidden' value='1' name='part1_qty'/></tr>
<tr name='inact1' title='56151124' style='display:none;'><td></td>
    <td>Send True2Go Meter? <input type='checkbox' name='part8' value='21292002590'/></td><input type='hidden' value='1' name='part8_qty'/></tr>
<tr><td>Strips</td><td><?php sbox('part2', $samp_strips,1,'wide2'); ?></td><td><?php sbox('part2_qty', range(1,10)); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Lancets</td><td><?php sbox('part3', $samp_lancets,1,'wide2'); ?></td><td><?php sbox('part3_qty', range(1,10)); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Control</td><td><?php sbox('part4', ptdme('A4256'),1,'wide2'); ?></td><input type='hidden' value='1' name='part4_qty'/></tr>
<tr><td>L/D</td><td><?php sbox('part5', ptdme('A4258'),1,'wide2'); ?></td><input type='hidden' value='1' name='part5_qty'/></tr>
<tr><td>Battery</td><td><?php sbox('part6', ptdme('A4235'),1,'wide2'); ?></td><td><?php sbox('part6_qty', range(1,2)); ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Misc</td><td><?php sbox('part7', ptdme2(array('SAMP','MISC')),1,'wide2'); ?></td><td><?php sbox('part7_qty', range(1,10)); ?></td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

I hope that makes sense and i'd be happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: for check box add the attribute checked=checked. for the input put the value in the value attribute

Answer (score 0):

For checkboxes you use `checked="checked"` or just `checked`
And for dropdowns you use `selected="selected"` or just `selected`

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

[Example here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

Answer (score 0):

to get a check box or radio button checked you have to set the checked attribute to checked for a combo box you must set the selected attribute to selected on the option element.

Comment: I'm actually working on a frameworks in PHP that would do most of the work you have up there in about 3 lines of code :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to complete an ethnicity dropdwon.  The code is easy to follow  and adaptable.  It uses mysql_ which is now deprecated but the principle holds.  As you can see, the way to do it is in SQL - you select all your lancets, meterkits, batteries etc SEPARATELY and build each dropdown one at a time.  Don't try to sort data in PHP when you can do it in SQL.  You're just going to end up writing buggy, difficlut to follow code that is terribly susceptible to minor spelling errors.

I do recommend that you reconsider your user interface.  Many diabetic patients are elderly and become easily confused when confronted with dropdowns.  They also don't see so well so you may end up with mis-ordering, something select boxes are terribly prone to and for which you are going to get blamed, even if it was the user at fault.  Abbreviations like c/s are unwise.  Even health professionals are likely to find that UI annoying and may be put off.

```
    $sql="Select ethnicitycode,ethnicitydesc from s_ethnicity where inuse=1 order by ethnicitydesc";
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$dbh);
    $optext="<select name='ethnicity1' class='select' onChange='Change()'><option value='0'>Choose Ethnicity</option>";
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {

                $option=$row2[ethnicitydesc];

                $code=$row2[ethnicitycode];

                if($row[ethnicitycode1]==$code){$selected="selected='selected'";}else{$selected="";}
                $optext=$optext.sprintf("<option value='%s'%s>%s</option>",$code,$selected,$option);
                } 

    $optext=$optext."</select>";
```